# Is RTP suitable for delivery of data files to multiple recipients?

Tags: rtp, rtcp

I have a need to transfer files from a single, centralized source to a several hundred client machines.  We currently use [UDPCast](http://udpcast.linux.lu/) to do this sort of thing, but are looking for more of a standards based approach to solving the problem.

I have been reading through the RTP RFC (1889) and notice that the protocol was primarily developed for streaming media (audio and/or video) to multiple clients.  It occurred to me that it might also satisfy my needs for file transfer as well.

Of course, I would need to be able to ensure that all "blocks" of the file that I'm sending are received by each client.

Is RTP suitable for transfer of data files?  Can RTCP be used to make sure that all clients receive all of the data that was sent?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Transfering a file needs guarantees in data delivery and integrity.  RTP is based on UDP, which does not guarantee either of those. Audio and Video do not require as much guarantees to remain coherant to users' senses, dropped data is hardly noticed.  You are better off running a TCP-based server that clients can download from when needed, such as with FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTP is not directly designed for reliable block transfer.  While you can shoehorn stuff on top of it to implement a reliable transfer protocol using RTP as a lower layer, this is stuffing a square peg in a round hole.

File transfer protocols exist in abundance; you should probably look at something like the Bittorrent protocol, or a subset of it since you apparently don't need peer-to-peer (but you can use it as a one-to-many protocol if you want).

Comment: Although banks / the financial industry in general seems to be fascinated with RTP and ASN for some reason... they do things like the op asks all the time